# Current time in millisecond in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How to get the current time in millisecond in MySQL.

So far what I've got is `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

**But it returns the current time in seconds.**

But I want the current time in **milliseconds** in UTC since '1970-01-01 00:00:00'   in MySQL.

*Any suggestion?*

Comment: would you please explain a bit more?

Comment: do you want current time with millisecond precision? or you want milliseconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC?

Comment: yes the second one. in utc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now), it sounds like you want

```
NOW(3)
```

... where the value 3 is used to specify that you want 3 digits of subsecond precision, i.e. milliseconds. (Unfortunately none of the examples in the docs show that being used, so it's relatively tricky for me to check this...)

To get that as a "milliseconds since the Unix epoch" value, you'd probably want to use:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(3)) * 1000
```

Comment: Actually I want it to return a long value. instead it returns a date.

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(6))` is maximum precision.

Comment: @SubrataDey: Looking a SQL Fiddle, I don't get a decimal - but it sounds like you just want a cast: `CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(3)) * 1000 AS BIGINT)` or similar (e.g. `ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW(3)) * 1000)`)

Comment: thanks. But I cannot upvote the answer. lacking reputation. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Thi is my answer;

```
mysql> Select curtime(4);
+------------+
| curtime(4) |
+------------+
| 13:27:20   |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or can also make this:

```
mysql> select conv( 
    ->             concat(
    ->                    substring(uid,16,3), 
    ->                    substring(uid,10,4), 
    ->                    substring(uid,1,8))
    ->                    ,16,10) 
    ->             div 10000 
    ->             - (141427 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) as current_mills
    -> from (select uuid() uid) as alias;
+---------------+
| current_mills |
+---------------+
| 1427995791797 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```